# Can I use a different version of Tensorflow to decrease my heroku slug size

Tags: tensorflow, heroku, keras, deployment

Tensorflow seems to take up a lot of space when installed on heroku. Is there a way where I can make tensorflow take up less space? Is there a lighter version of tensorflow? I am only using it to load a pretrained model and tokenize text, I don't need the whole 500MB library.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for whatever reason tensorflow 2 is much bigger than any other version. If you go to the pypi for tensorflow you can see how big each version is. This will help you reduce your slug size. Also, you could use tensorflow.js instead.